# NextJS support in WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm, next.js

Is there any plan in Webstorm (or IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate) roadmap to have a first class support for Next.js? Just like how Angular and plain-React are supported currently.

Comment: Most likely no because Next.js is just react with node and js which are all supported.

Comment: No, we have no plans for providing first class support for it - as it's mentioned above, it's more or less the same as plain React. What features do you miss namely?

Comment: @lena there are some "jsx is used without importing react" warnings - next.js is doing the "import React" stuff and its really annoying.

Comment: Also, auto syntax highlighting for styled-jsx automatically would be nice! right now you have to insert a comment on every component: https://github.com/zeit/styled-jsx#webstormidea

Comment: there is a way to configure the inspection in *JavaScript | General | Missing React import with JSX*;

Comment: thx - now the styled-components plugin also solve the other issue with highlighting

Comment: Features I currently miss: Automatically check that next.js is a node.js project, ''public" and "pages" are root folder.

Comment: @lena nowadays Next.js is not about only React anymore, it's also a backend framework: https://2020.stateofjs.com/en-US/technologies/back-end-frameworks/

Answer (score 14):

A bit late, but adding to this as it's a popular answer is to simply replace the scripts `npx create-react-app` with `npx create-next-app` and  it should be identical to doing it manually outside the application.

Comment: however support for basic features like debugging is not available